# getSpeed in background

Tags: java, android

Hey I'm trying to get user speed from my app, when it run on background.
I'm using getSpeed() and it works when my app run on foreground.
I tried to use Service for that but it give me the speed only after several minutes and i need it more frequently.
I read that google change their terms but I'm not sure if there is something to do about it (maybe some permission or leave the app running as floating).

Here is my code:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";

    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener locationListener;
    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService
                (Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new SpeedActionListener();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, locationListener);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBind");
        return null;
    }

    private class SpeedActionListener implements android.location.LocationListener {
        private static final String TAG = "SpeedoActionListener";

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            if(location != null) {
                if(location.hasSpeed()){
                    double mySpeed = location.getSpeed();
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current speed: " + String.valueOf(mySpeed * 3.6));
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you all!

Comment: You should take a loot at `AsyncTask` : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask

Answer (score 0):

Your observed behaviour is correct. When your app is running in background, your app does only receive location updates a few times per hour.

You can find more information here: [Background Location Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits)

The page also mentions some possible solutions:

> Consider whether your app's use cases for running in the background cannot succeed at all if your app receives infrequent location updates. If this is the case, you can retrieve location updates more frequently by performing one of the following actions:
>
> - Bring your app to the foreground.
>   Start a **foreground service** in your app by calling startForegroundService(). When such a foreground service is active, it appears as an ongoing notification in the notification area.
> - Use elements of the Geofencing API, such as the GeofencingApi interface, which are optimized for minimizing power use.
> - Use a passive location listener, which may receive faster location updates if there are foreground apps requesting location updates at a faster rate.

The easiest solution might be to promote your service to a foreground service, but this requires a notification being visible the whole runtime in phone's notification center. You can read about a Android Foreground Service [here](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-foreground-service-example/).

The other proposed solutions depend on the use case you have. Another interesting blog post about the foreground service and it's alternatives can be found [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/12/effective-foreground-services-on-android_11.html).